# Converse of ΔU = 0 for isothermal processes: is it true?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

For an ideal gas undergoing an isothermal process $\Delta U = 0.$

But is the converse true? Let's say, $\Delta U$ for an ideal gas is *zero*. Is its temperature constant then? Can we say that it's undergoing an isothermal process?

Comment: If  there is ongoing reaction between ideal gases at constant V in isolated container, delta U = 0 but T can change very much.

Comment: We can't say that the ideal gas has undergone an isothermal process.  All we can say is that, at the two end points of the process, the temperature is the same.

Comment: @ChetMiller That's a valuable point, and I agree with you. But for state functions, I believe it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @electronpusher I agree also with poitnik’s comment

Answer (score 1):

Isothermal process means that the temperature of the system (here, ideal gas) is constant throughout the process.

For an ideal gas, internal energy is a function of temperature only and its change can be expressed by:

$$\Delta U=nC_V\,\Delta T$$

Therefore,

$\Delta U=0$ implies that $\Delta T=0$.

However, this only implies that initial temperature and final temperature are same.

The temperature may/may not be constant throughout the process.

Therefore, $\Delta U=0$ is not a sufficient condition to say that ideal gas is undergoing isothermal process.

Comment: U is independent of path. the Second condition to define an ideal gas involves V or P: [partialU/partialV][T]  equals zero. This strongly implies that a constant internal energy for an ideal gas means isothermal. Of course if there is a change in chemical potential E or obviously a latent heat change at constant T this isn't true. This is like saying Boyle's Law takes place at constant T and U instead of just constant T.